# Return posted data with res.send after post request?

Tags: javascript, express

I have a post route that receives an array of strings from req.body. It then takes the array and queries my local MySQL database a few times and retrieves some data that I am wanting to send back to the client (react) and then store in state.

The problem I'm having is storing my data in an array to successfully send via the res.send or res.json method.

I believe it may be an issue solved with handling the scope in another manner but I am stumped on this one.

I've tried moving the location of the original array variable declaration, but at best with `res.send(aisleArr)`, I receive only an empty array.

I also tried not declaring  'aisleArr' before the push method, thinking that it would create a global aisleArr object but to no avail.

```
router.post('/complete', (req, res) => {

  const list = req.body;

  let aisleArr = [];

  list.map(item =>
    db.item.findAll({
      where: {'$item.name$': item}
      })
      .then(data => data.map( data => 
        db.aisle.findAll({
          where: {'$aisle.id$': data.dataValues.aisleId, '$aisle.storeId$': 2}
        }).then( result => { 

          if(result[0]){
            aisleArr.push(result[0].name)
          }else{
            console.log('no match')}})
        ) 
      )
    )
res.send(aisleArr)
});
```

In the client console only an empty array is received upon res.send completing.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may need to make sure the `map` iterator is complete before you send the value. Even though the return values are chained with promises, the assignment to `aisleArr` is not and `res.send` is probably firing before the iterator is finished. Using async/await would provide an easier way to ensure that assignment is complete before moving forward.

For example:

```
router.post('/complete', async (req, res) => {

  const list = req.body;

  const aisleArr = await list.map(item =>
    db.item.findAll({
      where: {'$item.name$': item}
    })
    .then(data =>
      data.map(newData =>
        db.aisle.findAll({
          where: {'$aisle.id$': newData.dataValues.aisleId, '$aisle.storeId$': 2}
        })
        .then(result => {
          if (result[0].name) {
            return result[0].name;
          } else {
            console.log('no match');
          }
        });
      );
    );
  ).filter(aisle => aisle);
  // the filter at the end will remove null values
  // (when nothing is returned from the last call to .then)

  res.send(aisleArr);
});
```

I did not run this so it may take a tweak or two, but I hope it's a good starting point. Overall, I think the main thing to watch out for is that the `map` is completed before you call `res.send`. It may be helpful to add some more console.logs to ensure that this is the issue.

Comment: Thank you! Following the code above is heading in the right direction. Async, await seems to definitely play into it. I have some fiddling to do as the array returns the correct number of expected elements, however the elements seem to be the promise response (I think?) - example:

**As seen in client console**
(4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}] 
0: {isFulfilled: false, isRejected: false}
1: {isFulfilled: false, isRejected: false}
2: {isFulfilled: false, isRejected: false}
3: {isFulfilled: false, isRejected: false}
length: 4
__proto__: Array(0)